# MyAssembly.dll.licenses files missing in the obj folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am configuring a GoCD Agent on a VM and all builds were compiling with MSBuild and VS2017 installed on the VM. 
At some point I needed to install VS2015 in order to get the office tools and in the middle of the installation I abort it. After that all the builds are failing, I can see an error due to a missing  MyAssembly.dll.licenses in the obj folder. I have already restarted the server and the issue still remains. I have windows server 2016 installed on the VM.

What are these files and how are they generated?
Am I missing some environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried Windows 10 SDK and it didn't work. I ended up reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 and my builds are now green again.